Fancy bibliography items
I'd like to add costumized icons (from fontawesome package) in front of each bibliographic entry in a beamer presentation.
This is the code:
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Bibliography}
\begin{thebibliography}{10}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[???]
\bibitem{A} A
\bibitem{B} B
\bibitem{C} C
\end{thebibliography}
\end{frame}

\end{document}

Substituting ??? with any command gives me an error.

Remeber you are always more likely to get help if you provide a full but minimal exmaple others can copy and test as is. Here we have to add preamble etc.

With the syntax \setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[foo] you can load a predefined template with the name foo. This template needs to be defined via \defbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{foo}{...}.
If you'd like to use custom code instead, use \setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{...}:
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\defbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{foo}{\faCat}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Bibliography}
\begin{thebibliography}{10}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[foo]
\bibitem{A} A
\bibitem{B} B
\bibitem{C} C
\end{thebibliography}

\bigskip

\begin{thebibliography}{10}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{\faCarrot}
\bibitem{A} A
\bibitem{B} B
\bibitem{C} C
\end{thebibliography}
\end{frame}

\end{document}



Thank you very much!

@jacopofurlan You're welcome!
